# How do I make less STOP chopping long lines by default?

Tags: less

The web seems to be full of resources for making `less` stop wrapping long lines by default and chop them instead. I have the opposite problem. It is chopping be default and I want to make it stop. I want word wrapping turned back on by default, but all I can find are instructions for the other way around. I've tried reversing them, but none of the methods seem to be employed to be reversed.

My problem developed about a month ago and is across a number of systems. I suspect it might actually be my dotfiles somewhere, but for the life of me I can't find it.

- `less` is not aliased to anything in my shell, it is not a function, nor  am I getting some binary other than the system default:

  ```
  $ which less
  /usr/bin/less
  ```
- I am not running with the `-S` argument:

  ```
  $ ps waux | grep less
   caleb     3151  0.0  0.0  13592  1036 pts/14   S+   16:06   0:00 less
  ```
- I do not have anything set in `~/.lesskey`:

  ```
  $ cat ~/.lesskey
  cat: /home/caleb/.lesskey: No such file or directory
  ```

And yet line chopping is turned on everywhere it is instantiated. I have to turn it off with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> every time.

The man page clearly states this is the opposite of the expected behavior:

```
$ man less
...
    -S or --chop-long-lines
        Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped (truncated)
        rather than wrapped.  That is, the portion  of  a  long line that does
        not fit in the screen width is not shown. The default is to wrap long
        lines; that is, display the remainder on the next line.
...
```

Because it is a default there doesn't seem to be a command line switch to turn this off. Where else could this be getting set so I can find it and eradicate it?

Comment: Which terminal client are you using, or are you on the console?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Termite + tmux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options are also taken from the `LESS` environment variable. Check if it has been set with `echo "$LESS"`.

Comment: `echo $LESS`: `-F -X -g -i -M -R -S -w -z-4`. Mercy where did all _those_ flags come from‽ Thanks I think I can track it down from there to find what messed with my env. I just couldn't find what channel it was reading from. I had looked at `$PAGER` early on when I thought it was just git giving me trougle but gave it up after trying `=less` directly.

Comment: @Caleb That's a lot of flags, alright. I'm personally very strict about letting applications change (mess with) my start-up files. Nothing goes into my dotfiles without me knowing what the changes are and the reasons why.

Comment: `git blame` informs me that I am directly responsible for copy and pasting a block out of zprezto's source into my own `.zprofile`.